# How to add style polyfill for Angular

Tags: angular, webpack, sass, bundle

I faced a problem, where our team developed an application on Angular 12 + we use Sass, and then our customer told us to add support for older browsers. The problem is we used style called `gap` which is poorly supported for example in Safari, so basically we decided to use polyfill for styles. We found `flex-gap-polyfill`. The problem is I don't know how to add it to the main bundle. It uses construction like

```
const flexGapPolyfill = require('flex-gap-polyfill');

flexGapPolyfill.process(YOUR_CSS /*, processOptions, pluginOptions */);
```

so it should probably be handled by `polyfill.ts` but how to do it stays a mystery